# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#

When I try to call the balance method I get the error below.I am trying to list the account holder with their account balance. Any help would be great.

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

```
public void balance(){
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; ++x)
        if (x < 5){
            Console.WriteLine("Account Holders Name===>{1}Has a balance of===>{2}",
                accountname[x], accountbal[x]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Format argument indices start at 0, not 1. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Account Holders Name===>{0}Has a balance of===>{1}",
    accountname[x], accountbal[x]);
```

Comment: now I get this ---->Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @randywhite30 - this is nothing to do with your array.  The error refers to your matching of second and later arguments to `Console.WriteLine` with the placeholders in the first (string) argument.  2nd arg -> {0}, 3rd arg -> {1] etc.

Comment: I had the loop going to 6 when the array only goes to 5

Comment: @randywhite30: It seems you had two different errors then. The error message you posted (mentioning argument lists) specifically refers to an error in the format string of `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I had the index error first but then the program ran then I recieved the second error.